# c++ how to read a cfg file more complex?

Tags: c++

I recently changed from c# to c++.
Ive been watching some tutorials on how to read a config file. I am probably asking it wrong, what I mean is:
I am making a program, but it's for multiple users. Every user will have his prefence on what will be in a textfile.
Example:
In my textfile ("items.txt"), i have default "ints" and configurable "ints".

```
10=5
90=2
50=9
```

In c#, if i remember correctly, i read all lines and if the line started with for example "10=", i splitted the text so my line would only be the configurable  int left and i can use that easly in my program, it was something like:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string str;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
if (line.StartsWith("10"))
{
str = line.Split('=')[1];
//I have what i need (str);
}
}
```

I did that for everything that i needed. So, what's the best way to do this in c++?

ALSO: I need to get a specific line for them, so i can use them all later on in my program.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why did you change from C# to C++? Use the right tool for the job; jobs for which C# is the right tool are not often jobs for which C++ is also the right tool.

Comment: Because im making tools for a game, and the best way for me to do this was in c++. Going back to c# would be a pain, So i just need to know this part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a library like `libconfig` http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/

Comment: Why don't you use JSON? you could build a simple class that has a default parameter and store everything in a file to act like a config file. (You could also search for library's for that)

Comment: @NaorHadar, I haven't heard about that, but it seems interresting. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try some libraries for complex configs, e.g. config4cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 things in your files:

1. lines, which we can read with [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline#Example)
2. keys (the part of the line before `=`)
3. values (the part after the `=`).

   We can split the key and value by finding the `=` character.

So, you get something like:

```
std::ifstream file(path);
if (!file) {
    std::cerr << "unable to open " << path << std::endl;
    return false;
}

for (std::string line; getline(file, line); ) {
    auto pos = line.find('=');
    if (pos == line.end()) {
        std::cerr << "skipping invalid line '" << line << "'\n";
        continue;
    }
    auto key = line.substr(0, pos);
    auto val = line.substr(pos);
    // do something with key,val
}
```

If you want to convert the key and value strings above into `int`, you can use a `std::stringstream` to do the conversion, or use `std::strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a C++ equivalent of the C# code you posted. This code by itself will compile, of course you have to fill something in for path instead of an empty string. If you need this somewhere in a method instead of as a program on itself, abandon the *int main()* and *return 0* of course. Reply to this if something is unclear. I tried to set it up the same way your C# code is structured, so you would understand everything.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string path = "";
    std::ifstream file(path); //open the file from path, might want to check file.fail()
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::string line;
    while (file >> line)
        lines.push_back(line);

    std::string str;
    for (const std::string& line : lines)
    {
        if (line.substr(0, 2).compare("10") == 0)
        {
            size_t foundIdx = line.find('=');
            str = line.substr(foundIdx + 1);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responds, I tried to do:

if (line.substr(0, 2).compare("ak47) == 0)
{
 size_t foundIdx = line.find('=');
 str = line.substr(foundIdx + 1);

cout << str;
}

I dont get anything, in my testfile, the only line is "ak47=180"

Comment: And yes, i specified a string path.

Comment: @gauthiercremers [`substr(0,2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) gets a string containing the first two characters - how could it ever compare equal to a 4-character string?

Comment: As user Useless stated, substr(0, 2) means a string from index 0 (start) that is 2 characters long. So it does not equal "starts with". I can't provide you a good answer if I don't know what you are planning on doing in the future with this, but a regular expression is a good way to match something at the start of a string for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well in C++ we now use [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

For your case - I'd use the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    // Simple config file
    std::string rules = "10=5\n  90=2\n50=9";

    std::regex single_rule_regex("[0-9]+\\=[0-9]+");
    std::regex single_rule_part_regex("[0-9]+");

    auto rules_begin = std::sregex_iterator(rules.begin(), 
                                            rules.end(), 
                                            single_rule_regex);
    auto rules_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (auto it = rules_begin; it != rules_end; ++it)
    {
        std::smatch rule_match = *it;
        std::string rule_str = rule_match.str();

        std::cout << rule_str << std::endl;

        // key=value
        auto parts = std::sregex_iterator(rule_str.begin(), 
                                          rule_str.end(), 
                                          single_rule_part_regex);
        std::string key = parts->str();
        std::string value = (++parts)->str();

        std::cout << key << " has " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output for the gives `rules` is:

> 10=5 
>   10 has 5  
>   90=2  
>   90 has 2  
>   50=9  
>   50 has 9